# I have many errors during deserialization request body in controller. But I see the last one in the log

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, deserialization

I have controller with complex request body object:

```
public class Request
{
    public Request(Entity[] entities)
    {
        Entities = Check.NotNullOrEmpty(entities, nameof(entities));
    }
    
    public Entity[] Entities { get; }
}

public class Entity
{
    public Entity(string name, string surname)
    {
        Name = Check.NotNullOrEmpty(name, nameof(name));
        Surname = Check.NotNullOrEmpty(surname, nameof(surname));
    }
    
    public string Name { get; }

    public string Surname { get; }
}
```

Where `Check.NotNullOrEmpty` looks like:

```
public static T[] NotNullOrEmpty<T>(T[] argumentValue, string argumentName) 
   => argumentValue != null && ((IEnumerable<T>) argumentValue).Any<T>() ? argumentValue : throw new ArgumentException("Argument '" + argumentName + "' must not be null or empty.");

public static string NotNullOrEmpty(string argumentValue, string argumentName)
{
  return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(argumentValue) ? argumentValue : throw new ArgumentException("Argument '" + argumentName + "' cannot be null or empty.");
}
```

For simple controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] Request request)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

And if I pass to controller request with only one element in Entities and this element has no name property

```json
{
  "entities": [
    {
      "surname": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

I expected error about argument `name`, that argument `name` cannot be null, In order for users of my method to receive a more understandable error. And this is what happens when trying to deserialize with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` for example.

But for my case I see error about "entities":

> An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
> ArgumentException: Argument 'entities' must not be null or empty.
> at Check.NotNullOrEmpty[T](T[] argumentValue, String argumentName)
> at Tools.Request..ctor(Entity[] entities) in C:\Users...\Models\Request.cs:line 13
> at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] )
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty conta
> inerProperty, ObjectConstructor`1 creator, String id)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty containerMember, JsonP
> roperty containerProperty, String id, Boolean& createdFromNonDefaultCreator)

I want to see an error about the inner element of the array, not the array itself.

I found the only solution, in Startup.cs, throw inner error:

```
services.AddMvcCore()
      .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => 
               options.SerializerSettings.Error = (sender, args) => throw args.ErrorContext.Error);
```

Anyway, It feels like and unsafe solution. Does anyone know of an alternative solution?

Comment: Can you share controller code also

Comment: Share implementation of `Check.NotNullOrEmpty<T>(T[] argumentValue, String argumentName)`.

Comment: BTW: I am not affiliated with the project but we made extraordinary good experience with [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/).

Comment: Hello! I added controller and Check.NotNullOrEmpty<T> code

Comment: Might the issue actually be with your Model binding? I suspect that your Request object is being constructed with a null or empty argument. You could test this easily by debugging or by printing out the contents in your Request constructor.

Comment: If I copy your code and JSON into a fiddle and do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(json)` I cannot reproduce the problem.  I am seeing *`System.ArgumentException: Argument 'name' cannot be null or empty.`* as required.  See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/q3PC9F.    Are you sure your application code isn't swallowing the error, or that your real code differs from the code you have shared?

Comment: In your real code, are you sure that the names of the `Entities` property and the `entities` constructor argument are identical except for case?  Json.NET matches properties to arguments using a case-invariant match so if your property is something like `Entites` or `EntityList` then you will get the exception you see.

Comment: I sure that my json is correct and I know that if I try deserialize json with JsonConvert.DeserializeObject I have expected error, I wrote about it in question. My problem is with deserialization in controller, NewtonsoftJsonInputormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync. If I debugging my code I see both problem, but due to newtonsoft inner error is hidden from me in log. Smth like the deserializer tries to complete deserialization and ignores invalid elements of Entities when deserializing the class Request.

Comment: Is entities null or an empty array in the call to the constructor?

Comment: Also what version of Newtonsoft.Json are you using?

Comment: > Is entities null or an empty array in the call to the constructor?

Empty array

Comment: > Also what version of Newtonsoft.Json are you using? 13.0.1